# android: one click listener on many imageviews in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imageview

I have the following scenario:

[image]

In a layout, I have imageviews aligned horizontally and vertically as shown in image.

First, which layout should be used for this purpose? RelativeLayout or FrameLayout? ListView inside the layout?

Also, instead of writing setOnClickListener for every imageview, how can I write just one click listener to get the clicked imageview?

Comment: Use `GridView` and use `setOnItemClickListener` to handle clicks

Comment: yup looks like a grideview to me as well

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi thanks, i would mark your answer correct, but also please provide this link http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html in the answer

Comment: Great it helped, I have also posted an answér so others can refer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'GridView' in the layout and use 'setOnItemClickListener' to handle click events,

You can find more details in below link
 [GridView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Answer (score 2):

A `GridView` is perfect for this. For more information on GridView, look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

As for your onClickListener question: there is no easy way to do this, but what you can do is something like this:

1. Have an array containing every ImageView id like so:

   ```
   public static final int[] IMAGE_VIEWS = {R.id.imageView1, R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView3 /*etc*/}; //Make sure to list from the first imageview to the last image view in correct order
   ```
2. Define an onClickListener

   ```
   private View.OnClickListener imageViewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_VIEWS.length; i++) {
               if (v.getId() == IMAGE_VIEWS[i]) {
                   doSomethingWithImageViewClick(i); //if ImageView 4 was clicked, variable 'i' will be 3 (because arrays start at index = 0).
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set the onClickListeners for all your imageViews:

   ```
   final ImageView view1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   view1.setOnClickListener(imageViewListener);
   //etc
   ```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**GridView** can achieve the effect. I think you can look at this [Grid View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/).